# The easiest algorithm to create a specific series of numbers

Tags: java, arraylist

```
var numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(24);
```

The `ArrayList` contains a series of increasing numbers. It starts with number one. For the next element, the number is increased by two (except for every third element, which increases by one).

I created it using this algorithm.

```
var number = -1;
for (var i = 1; i <= 24; i++) {
    if (i % 3 != 0) {
        number += 2;
    } else {
        number += 1;
    }
    numbers.add(number);
}

[1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23, 24, 26, 28, 29, 31, 33, 34, 36, 38, 39]
```

However, I'm not sure if it's optimal.

Is it possible to improve / change the algorithm for better, please?

Thank you

Comment: Is there any mathematical law ? What is the logic, the pattern ?

Comment: As with what azro said what pattern/function are these numbers following in?

Comment: The elements of the array are triads. The first starts with 1. The second has +2. The third has +1. The fourth (the first of the following three) has +2 and this is how it repeats.

Comment: So the values go +1, +2, +1, +2, +2, +1, +2, +2, +1, +2, +2, +1, +2, +2 and so on?

Comment: Yes.  Exactly like that.

Comment: `int input = ...; int[] offset = {1, 3, 4}; int result = (input/3)*5 + offset[input%3];`

Comment: So I solved it - the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out like that.

```
var number = -1;
for (var i = 1; i <= 24; i++) {
    number += (i % 3) + Math.abs(Math.signum((i % 3) - 2));
    numbers.add(number);
}

[1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23, 24, 26, 28, 29, 31, 33, 34, 36, 38, 39]
```